# How to toggle with map function

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, toggle

I want to use toggle with map function.

I've tried many things, but I returned to the first code. I know what's the problem(I use the map function, but I use only one toggle variable), but I don't know how to fix it.

This is my code.

```
 const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(true);
 const toggleFunction = () => {
    setToggle(!toggle);
  };
```

```
{wholeData.map((image)=>{
   return(
      <TouchableOpacity
         key={image.ROWNUM}
         onPress={() => navigation.navigate("DetailStore", {
            contents: image,
            data: wholeData
         })}  
      >

.
.
.

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => toggleFunction()}>
   {toggle ? (
      <View style={{marginRight: 11}}>
         <AntDesign name="hearto" size={24} color="#C7382A" />
            </View>
               ) : (
            <View style={{marginRight:11}}>
         <AntDesign name="heart" size={24} color="#C7382A" />
      </View>
   )}
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've noticed, using a single state for all the toggles won't give you what you want.  All you have to do is move your toggle function inside the component you return when you're mapping over your images.

As an unrelated note, you could also simplify your second TouchableOpacity a bit, since the only thing that changes is the icon name.

For example:

```js
// New component
const ListImage = ({ image }) => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(true);
  const toggleFunction = () => {
    setToggle(!toggle);
  };
  return (
     <TouchableOpacity
       key={image.ROWNUM}
       onPress={() => navigation.navigate("DetailStore", {
         contents: image,
         data: wholeData
       })}  
     >
     ...
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => toggleFunction()}>
       <View style={{ marginRight: 11 }}>
         <AntDesign
           name={toggle ? "hearto" : "heart"}
           size={24}
           color="#C7382A"
         />
       </View>
     </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}

// in current component

{wholeData.map((image) => {
  return <ListImage image={image} />
})}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but it caused an error 'Rendered more hooks than during the previous render'. Can you help me with that?

Comment: That's my fault, hooks should only be called in the body of a function component. I edited my answer to show that you should move the return of the map to a custom component.